# Determining if process has died?

Tags: android, aidl

Is there a way to determine whether a process has died?  I have a system service that stores information on each client that connects to it.  When the process that is hosting that client dies, I would like to clean up my cache.  I've searched all over google but it seems that this is not possible :(

One solution that I came across was using Binder's linkToDeath, but that design does not mesh really well with my current design.  Is there an alternative ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't mesh well"?

Answer (score 0):

The state of Thread you can determine by using isAlive() method to this Thread, or use getState() to determine thread state more precisely.

Binder has method isBinderAlive(), but I didn't use it so can't add anything uncovered in officical docs.

Comment: Thanks for idea.  However, I believe that will only tell me if the current Thread has died.  I was hoping for a solution that would tell me whether the entire process has died.

Answer (score 0):

The approach of using `linkToDeath` is the only one which I know of.

Normally here's what I would do:

- Have a class, `IMySystemService.aidl` which is implemented by your system service.
- Have a listener, `IMySystemServiceListener.aidl` which is implemented by each client.
- Add a method such as `IMySystemService.addListener(IMySystemServiceListener listener)`

Then, use `linkToDeath` on the listener within your system service to get a callback for when each client dies. You can then clean up the relevant parts of your cache.

If your project is at all complex already, you probably have some suitable per-client listener already?

Can you answer why `linkToDeath` doesn't work for your design?

One common pattern for caches is to use [WeakHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) for your cache - but this only works if you have a key object which is garbage-collected when the client disappears. I believe that this, in turn, can only be achieved using `linkToDeath` so we're back to where we started!